# ejabberd start crashes in user_drv module

Tags: ubuntu, erlang, ejabberd

I am using ejabber-14.07 and erlang 17 (v6.4), and after updating my ubuntu to 16.04 I have troubles with ejabberd start, it crashes

```
{error_logger,{{2016,8,4},{12,20,35}},"~s~n",["Error in process <0.30.0> on node 'nodeej@marinakr' with exit value: {undef,[{group,start,[<0.30.0>,{}],[]},{user_drv,start_user,0,[{file,\"user_drv.erl\"},{line,154}]},{user_drv,server1,3,[{file,\"user_drv.erl\"},{line,114}]}]}\n"]}
{error_logger,{{2016,8,4},{12,20,45}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{supervisor_bridge,user_sup,['Argument__1']}},{pid,<0.29.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,nouser,[{gen_server,init_it,6,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,322}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}},{ancestors,[kernel_sup,<0.10.0>]},{messages,[]},{links,[<0.11.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,1598},{stack_size,27},{reductions,418}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,8,4},{12,20,45}},supervisor_report,[{supervisor,{local,kernel_sup}},{errorContext,start_error},{reason,nouser},{offender,[{pid,undefined},{name,user},{mfargs,{user_sup,start,[]}},{restart_type,temporary},{shutdown,2000},{child_type,supervisor}]}]}
{error_logger,{{2016,8,4},{12,20,45}},crash_report,[[{initial_call,{application_master,init,['Argument__1','Argument__2','Argument__3','Argument__4']}},{pid,<0.9.0>},{registered_name,[]},{error_info,{exit,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,user,nouser}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}},[{application_master,init,4,[{file,"application_master.erl"},{line,133}]},{proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,237}]}]}},{ancestors,[<0.8.0>]},{messages,[{'EXIT',<0.10.0>,normal}]},{links,[<0.8.0>,<0.7.0>]},{dictionary,[]},{trap_exit,true},{status,running},{heap_size,376},{stack_size,27},{reductions,117}],[]]}
{error_logger,{{2016,8,4},{12,20,45}},std_info,[{application,kernel},{exited,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,user,nouser}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}},{type,permanent}]}
{"Kernel pid terminated",application_controller,"{application_start_failure,kernel,{{shutdown,{failed_to_start_child,user,nouser}},{kernel,start,[normal,[]]}}}"}
```

I tried to find solution,but still don't know fow to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created own gen_mod with name "group", but name "group" already reserverd for native erlang module. It tried to use my module and crashed. All I need is another name for module.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is

```
{undef, [
         {group,start,[<0.30.0>,{}],[]},
         {user_drv,start_user,0,[{file,\"user_drv.erl\"},{line,154}]},
         {user_drv,server1,3,[{file,\"user_drv.erl\"},{line,114}]}
        ]}
```

So it's trying to call `group:start(<0.30.0>,{})` but the function is not defined. You should start by checking that there is a module named `group`, that it has a function `start` that takes a pid and a tuple, and that it's getting compiled without errors.